# Undefined at the end of a while loop

Tags: javascript

So this is my first time asking a question on stack overflow. My program is super simple and is just a practice that my friend is having me do to learn more about coding. Long story short here is my code:

```
let blocks = [
['H','L','S','J','U','B'],
['O','O','N','O','S','O'],
['M','V','O','Y','A','O'],
['E','E','W','' ,'' ,'' ]
];


let blocks_run = function(i,j) {
  while (i < blocks.length) {
    return blocks[i][j] + blocks_run(i+1,j)
  }
}

blocks_run(0,0);
```

for some reason, the response always returns undefined at the end.

e.g.

```
HOMEundefined
```

I just want to know why it's adding undefined to the end.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using a loop for the escape condition of a recursive function seems unusual. I'd use an `if` statement, and have the escape condition return the resulting value.

Comment: Agreeing with slappy, I think this is a bit of a strange exercise for a beginner to practice coding with. `Recursive functions` can be very useful, but they generally make `loops` unnecessary (and vice versa). I'd recommend practicing these two techniques separately.

Comment: Thank you both slappy and Cat, I am probably going to avoid recursive loops until I have a  better understanding of coding, but I appreciate the quick responses anyway! I've changed my code to match slappy's suggestion and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let blocks = [
['H','L','S','J','U','B'],
['O','O','N','O','S','O'],
['M','V','O','Y','A','O'],
['E','E','W','' ,'' ,'' ]
];


let blocks_run = function(i,j) {
  while (i < blocks.length) {
    return blocks[i][j] + (blocks_run(i+1,j) ?? '');
  }
}

console.log(blocks_run(0,0));
```

Another possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
let blocks_run = function(i,j) {
  while (i < blocks.length) {
    return blocks[i][j] + blocks_run(i+1,j)
  }
}
```

This function uses `while` instead of `if` to execute a `return` statement which recursively calls the function. If the condition fails because `i` is out of bounds, it doesn't explicitly return anything, which in JavaScript means the function returns `undefined`.

Depending on what you want, you could try

```
let blocks_run = function(i,j) {
  if (i < blocks.length) {
    return blocks[i][j] + blocks_run(i+1,j)
  }
  return ""; // not undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a loop since it'll never run more than one iteration. The conditional operator will allow you to put the whole function body into a single expression.

```js
let blocks = [
['H','L','S','J','U','B'],
['O','O','N','O','S','O'],
['M','V','O','Y','A','O'],
['E','E','W','' ,'' ,'' ]
];


const blocks_run = (i, j) => 
  i < blocks.length ? blocks[i][j] + blocks_run(i+1,j) : '';

console.log(blocks_run(0,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let blocks = [
['H','L','S','J','U','B'],
['O','O','N','O','S','O'],
['M','V','O','Y','A','O'],
['E','E','W','' ,'' ,'' ]
];


let blocks_run = function(i,j) {
  while (i < blocks.length) {
    return blocks[i][j] + blocks_run(i+1,j)
  }
  return '';
}

console.log(blocks_run(0,0));
```

Your recursion function by default is returning `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

**On the last row, you're still retrieving the next row**, which is undefined.

Recursive functions need to have a "base case" that tells them to stop recursing.

```js
let blocks = [
  ['H', 'L', 'S', 'J', 'U', 'B'],
  ['O', 'O', 'N', 'O', 'S', 'O'],
  ['M', 'V', 'O', 'Y', 'A', 'O'],
  ['E', 'E', 'W',  '',  '',  '']
];


let blocks_run = function(row, col) {
  while (row < blocks.length) {
    return row + 1 < blocks.length 
      ? blocks[row][col] + blocks_run(row + 1, col)
      : blocks[row][col];
  }
}
console.log(blocks_run(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something in the event that `i >= blocks.length`, for example:

```
  while (i < blocks.length) {
    return blocks[i][j] + blocks_run(i+1,j)
  }
  return '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactored for readability

```
let blocks_run = function(i,j) {
  /* base case */
  if (i == blocks.length) {
    return '';
  }

  return blocks[i][j] + blocks_run(i+1,j);
}
```

You see, this is how recursion works; `blocks_run` needs to return *something*, so when the recursion terminates and you haven't specified a base case, you get the return value of `undefined`. Since the function that called `blocks_run` the last time was indeed the same function, the while condition terminated and you ended up with + `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

For the last iteration while loop inside your method won't run as `i` value would be equal to `blocks.length`. As your method is returning nothing when while condition becomes false. It means it is returning `undefined` by default. That's what is concatenated in the last. So return empty string to resolve this issue.

**Solution:**

```
let blocks = [
['H','L','S','J','U','B'],
['O','O','N','O','S','O'],
['M','V','O','Y','A','O'],
['E','E','W','' ,'' ,'' ]
];


let blocks_run = function(i,j) {
  while (i < blocks.length) {
    return blocks[i][j] + blocks_run(i+1,j)
  }
  return ''
}

blocks_run(0,0);
```